# Are there any good reviews on the mouse and human conservation in coding and gene regulatory module regions?

Tags: homology

I was looking for reviews that deal with conservation between mouse and human of proteins, noncoding RNAs, gene regulatory module (such as promoters and enhancers), gene regulatory networks post the mouse genome sequencing era

Comment: you can look at the conservation tracks in UCSC genome browser.. or download latest MAF file from there.. You can do the analysis yourself.. You wont find reviews on this specific question.